# Rotate an image on top of another canvas image

Tags: javascript, canvas

Currently, I am making a game and in need of making the image rotate toward the cursor. I am using node but the image is in a js tag in the HTML file that uses ctx to draw the image.

If I put a `ctx.rotate(angle);` pretty much anywhere it will rotate everything; player, map, etc. I need help so that only the player is rotated

this is a simplified version of my code:

```
<canvas id="ctx" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
  //game
    var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");

    var WIDTH = 200;
    var HEIGHT = 200;
    var Img = {};

    //player
    Img.player = new Image();
    Img.player.src = '/client/img/player.png';

    var Player = function(/*node*/){
      ctx.drawImage(Img.player, ...);
    }

    //map
    Img.map = new Image();
    Img.map.src = '/client/img/map.png';

  //display everything
  setInterval(function(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,200,200);
        drawMap();
        for(var i in Player.list)
            Player.list[i].draw();
    },1000/60);

//functions

  //move map so that player is always in the middle
    var drawMap= function(){
        var x = WIDTH/2 - Player.list[/*node*/].x;
        var y = HEIGHT/2 - Player.list[/*node*/].y;
        ctx.drawImage(Img.map,x,y);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you doing `ctx.save()` before then restoring it after rotating by doing `ctx.restore()`.

Comment: what does save and restore do?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what you may be looking for

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");

const WIDTH = 500,
  HEIGHT = 500;

document.getElementById("ctx").height = HEIGHT;
document.getElementById("ctx").width = WIDTH;


var Player = {
  x: 50,
  y: 55,
  angle: 0
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
  var x = event.clientX - Player.x,
    y = event.clientY- Player.y,
    angle = Math.atan2(y,x);
  Player.angle = angle

})

function draw() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(Player.x, Player.y);
  ctx.rotate(Player.angle);
  ctx.translate(-Player.x, -Player.y);
  ctx.fillRect(Player.x, Player.y, 20, 20);
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.fillRect(150, 50, 20, 20);
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mero789y/qz7b3tkh/7/) here

Hope this helps!

Comment: the jsfiddle is not working for me but the snippet is, maybe the mouse listener doesn't work on jsfiddle?

And I have two images while only trying to rotate one, but instead both rotate.

Comment: The `save` and `restore` methods save the current state of the canvas then restores it after doing the code in between the save and restore methods